# Laravel MonoLog, pushProcessor not Logging Addition attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, monolog

I want to be able to add a unique id (Uid) to my logging.

In **Example 1:** Which is depended on `config/logging.php` and `ProcessorTap` files below is not working as expected. The logging is configured to use `stdout` which refers to the `ProcessorTap` class that is suppose to add a Uid, when the log statement is created (in accordance with `UidProcessor`)

**Example 2:** Which uses purely Mono classes works as expected.

**Why isnt Example 1 adding the `Uid` to the logs, when laravel `("laravel/framework": "5.7.*")` should be using Monolog classes as well ?**

**Example 1**: When this api is invoked, the output for `Log::info('test')` does not include UiD

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
   Log::info('test'); //output = [2020-03-24 04:51:16] local.INFO: test  
});
```

config/logging.php:

```
   'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stdout'),   //.env LOG_CHANNEL=stdout    
    'stdout' => [
                 'driver' => 'monolog',
                 'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
                 'with' => [
                     'stream' => 'php://stdout',
                 ],
                'tap' => [
                   ProcessorTap::class,
                ],
             ]
```

ProcessorTap:

```
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;

class ProcessorTap
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        $logger->pushProcessor(new UidProcessor());
    }
}
```

**Example 2**: Working correctly the Uid (a484a6729e14996c0af1)
 is added to the log for `$logger->info('test')`

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $logger = new Logger('main');
    $logger->pushProcessor(new UidProcessor(20)); 
    $logger->info('test'); // output = [2020-03-24 04:57:26] main.INFO: test [] {"uid":"a484a6729e14996c0af1"}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a laravel (5.7)/mono version specific issue, but I was able to resolve the via iterating via the handlers and calling pushProcessor

```
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;

class ProcessorTap
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
         collect($logger->getHandlers())->each(function ($handler) {
               $handler->pushProcessor(new UidProcessor());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! Adding it to the handlers instead to the general logger, did the trick!